# How to replace even values in string with ASCII value?

Tags: java, arrays, string, char

Suppose I have a string as `ABCDEFG`. I want to replace the even values of this string with their ASCII value. How should I do?

```java
//STRING IS STORED IN str
for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
    if (i % 2 != 0) { //FOR EVEN SPACES
        int m = str.charAt(i);
        //GOT ASCII VALUE OF even spaces
        System.out.println("Converted ASCII VALUES ARE" + m);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are almost there, you simply need to build the resulting string.
`String`s are immutable, so replacing would create a new String each time.
I would suggest a `StringBuilder` for this task, but you can also do it manually.

The result would look like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "ABCDEF";
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        if (i % 2 != 0) {
            int m = str.charAt(i);
            sb.append(m); // add the ascii value to the string
        } else {
            sb.append(str.charAt(i)); // add the normal character
        }
    }
    System.out.println(sb.toString());
}
```

Output:

```
A66C68E70
```

Answer (score 0):

- Method [`charAt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt(int)) returns *char* value at the specified index.
- Method [`codePointAt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#codePointAt(int)) returns *unicode code point* at the specified index.

```java
String str = "ABCDEFG";

String str2 = IntStream.range(0, str.length())
        .mapToObj(i -> {
            if (i % 2 == 0)
                return String.valueOf(str.charAt(i));
            else
                return String.valueOf(str.codePointAt(i));
        }).collect(Collectors.joining());

System.out.println(str2); // A66C68E70G
```

---

<sup>See also: [Change numbers to letters in a int array and return String](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65507166/14838237)</sup>