# Change numbers to letters in a int array and return String in java

Tags: java, arrays, string, numbers, alphabet

I have an `int array (b[])` with a random length and  random integers. I want to leave integers lower than 9 to how they are, i want to change the numbers `9-35` to letters `A-Z`. and i want do put `()` around all numbers higher than `35`. So `b[] = {1,10,36}` would generate a `String 1A(36)`. My try:

```java
int b[] = {99, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10, 35, 24};  //sample input
char[] hilfsarray = new char[b.length];
char[] alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVW".toCharArray();

for (int k = 0; k < hilfsarray.length; k++) //overwrite all positons with *
    hilfsarray[k] = '*';

for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
    int p = b[0] - 10;
    if (b[i] < 9 && b[i] <= 35) {
        hilfsarray[i] = alphabet[p];
    }
    return Arrays.toString(hilfsarray);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this code will do your job. It uses Java-8, StreamAPI:

```java
public String someMethod() {
    int[] items = {99, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10, 35, 24}; // sample input
    String[] alphabet =
            "A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z".split(",");

    return Arrays.stream(items)
            .mapToObj(item -> (item > 9 && item <= 35) ?
                    alphabet[item - 10] : "(" + item + ")")
            .reduce("", String::concat);
}
```

Sample output:

```
(99)(2)(3)(4)(5)AZO
```

Answer (score 0):

You can interpret numbers in the range `10-35` as *characters* and shift their *code points* by `55` to get *code points* of uppercase letters `65-90`:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] a = {1, 10, 36};
    int[] b = {99, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10, 35, 24};

    System.out.println(custom(a)); // 1A(36)
    System.out.println(custom(b)); // (99)2345AZO
}
```

```java
public static String custom(int[] arr) {
    return Arrays.stream(arr).mapToObj(i -> {
        if (i > 9 && i < 36)
            return Character.toString(i + 55);
        else if (i > 35)
            return "(" + i + ")";
        else
            return String.valueOf(i);
    }).collect(Collectors.joining());
}
```

---

<sup>See also: [Replace non ASCII character from string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65375639/14838237)</sup>